# HTML5 <audio> differing behavior on Chrome Mac/Win and Safari Mac/Win

Tags: windows, google-chrome, safari, html5-audio

I'm inserting an `<audio>` tag into a page. This works fine in Chrome and Safari on Mac, but on both Chrome and Safari in Windows the tag is inserted but the audio never plays.  I've stripped the code down to the minimum, and it's now ridiculously simple.  I just have no idea why Windows is being difficult.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>
            test
        </title>
        <script type="application/x-javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="application/x-javascript">
        $('body').html('<audio src="./audio/myfile.mp3" autoplay></audio>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Interestingly, if I remove all JS and just insert the `<audio>` tag into the `<body>`, Chrome Win works but Safari Win still doesn't.  Kind of a secondary question, but does Safari Win require QuickTime (not currently installed) in order to use the `<audio>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does Safari Win require QuickTime (not currently installed) in order to use the  tag

Yes it does.

Comment: Well that solved half the problem. The other half (Chrome) I solved by calling .play() on the `<audio>` object after inserting it.

Comment: It kinda makes sense. When the tag was inserted by a script it can be easily started by the script. Currently there are no issues cocerning autoplay behaviour, I suggest you create one, that way you can ensure if this is indeed expected bahaviour of just a glitch.

Comment: @dosboy I never knew HTML5 depended on scripts for working components... I wonder how that would affect some unknown place that have no scripts, if that even exists.

Comment: @Cawas We are talking about elements **inserted by scripts**. At that point you can safely assume scripting is enabled.

Comment: vbence forget script enabled - that's a choice who's dealing with it wanted to do. Also `<audio>` doesn't need to be inserted by script. What I'm wondering is about some weird device I didn't think of that have no **support** to scripts at all.

Comment: @Cawas The question was about `autoplay` behavior when the *element is inserted by a script*.

Comment: @Cawas They have the `controls` attribute, so in theory you can access multimedia functionality without scripting. So your *weird device* has the green light :)